# Are past/present progessive and past/present perfect verb form, nonfinite?

Tags: perfect-aspect, progressive-aspect, nonfinite-verbs, finite-verbs

I read that nonfinite verb form end in ***-ed***,***-ing*** or starts with ***to*** and another definition where nonfinite verb form show no tense.

But on the other hand, I've read there are past and present progressive verb forms. They start with *is/are/am* and end in ***-ing*** for present tense. In past form they start with *was/were* and end in ***-ing***.

Similar thing for present/past perfect form except it uses different starting words and ends in ***-ed***.

Are these verb phrase which have forms in the past and present, nonfinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb phrases used in constructing the progressive tenses contain both finite and non-finite verbs.

For example (finite verbs italicized, non-finite verbs bolded):

"I *am* **learning** to **play** the piano."

"I *have* never **been** there before, but I *plan* to **go** in the future."

"He *has* **been** **studying** chemistry for many years."

Comment: Note that all the examples of tensed verbs above are Auxiliary verbs. It is ***the first auxiliary verb*** in a verb phrase that is tensed; all succeeding verbs in that verb phrase are non-finite forms (infinitive, present participle, perfect participle). The only exception to this rule is a simple sentence with only one verb and no auxiliaries, in which case that verb is tensed.